# Java Eclips server jvm.dll problem

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

Try to use tips for Eclipse performance I try to add option in eclipse.ini like:

```
-vm C:\glassfish3\jdk\jre\bin\server
```

But it stucks for projects big enough - so I have kill task.
What can be the reason, what start to check ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need check if -vm C:\glassfish3\jdk\jre\bin\server on the first line of eclipse.ini